# Using IBMMQ amqmdnet.dll from a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I've developed a library using the latest IBM amqmdnet.dll assembly, 9.1.3

When I run the .NET Core console application (2.2) I got the following exception

`TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

I've disassembled the file with dotPeek and it references System.Web

[image]

Standing at [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm) it supports .NET Core. The assembly I've created is a standard .NET Class library and when referenced by a .NET Full Framework console application it works.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: The version number is probably wrong.  You can edit notepad the .proj file to correct.  Often this happens when a project is updated to new version of Net.  I would create a new project and add library that is giving errors.   Then compare the new project proj file with old and check versions.  This usually works but not always.  You may also try to target project to Net 3.5 instead of 4.0.  What version of Net is installed?

Comment: `amqmdnet.dll` only for .net framework not core.  In the documentation link you provided it states "From IBM MQ Version 9.1.1, the amqmdnetstd.dll library is available for .NET Standard support on Windows. Sample applications, including source files, are also supplied; see Sample applications for .NET.", so I suggest you use `amqmdnetstd.dll`.

Comment: @JoshMc if you put this as answer I'll vote and accept it, thanks

Comment: While the new answer posted provides additional information that IBM now places the .net standard dll in NuGet, it is not a solution for your original problem that you were attempting to use `amqmdnet.dll` instead of `amqmdnetstd.dll`.  I'm unsure why you removed the accept from my answer and accepted tommytarheel's answer.

Comment: I do not believe the new answer you accepted solves the problem you had.  It would be better as a comment since it does not provide a solution to your original problem only since additional information.    If you had asked how to obtain `amqmdnetstd.dll` the new answer would fit but that was not the question or problem you faced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found myself checking this StackOverflow question and the documentation links provided, and I see there is now a NuGet package available from IBM starting with version 9.1.4: [IBMMQDotnetClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient/#)

Answer (score 5):

`amqmdnet.dll` is only for .net framework not core.

In the documentation [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm) you provided it states:

> From IBM MQ Version 9.1.1, the amqmdnetstd.dll library is available for .NET Standard support on Windows. Sample applications, including source files, are also supplied; see Sample applications for .NET.

I suggest you use `amqmdnetstd.dll`.